# Trouble casting JMS TopicSession as AQjmsSession

Tags: java, session, jms, weblogic, jms-topic

I'm trying to browse messages in a topic using `TopicBrowser`. To call the correct `createBrowser` method that will return a `TopicBrowser` object, I need to cast my `topicSession` variable to `AQjmsSession`.

```
private InitialContext initialContext;
private TopicConnection topicConnection;
private TopicSession topicSession;
private Topic topic;

private TopicConnectionFactory topicFactory;

private TextMessage message;

private void initTopic(Context context, String topicName) throws NamingException, JMSException {
    System.out.println("initializing the queue...");
    topicFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
    topicConnection = topicFactory.createTopicConnection();

    //queueConnection.setExceptionListener(this);
    topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    System.out.println("session created, lookup queue: " + topicName);

    topic = (Topic)context.lookup(topicName);
    System.out.println("done...");
}

private void readTopicMessage() throws JMSException {
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("Starting the subscriber");
    TopicBrowser topicBrowser = ((AQjmsSession) topicSession).createBrowser(topic, SUBSCRIBER);
    Enumeration msgs = topicBrowser.getEnumeration();
    //topicConnection.start();
    System.out.println("Topic started\n");
    if (!msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println("No messages in topic");
    } else {
        while (msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(">>> message count: " + ++counter);

            Message message = (Message) msgs.nextElement();
            System.out.println("MessageID: " + message.getJMSMessageID() + "\tPriority: " + message.getJMSPriority() + "\tDeliveryMode: " + message.getJMSDeliveryMode());
            System.out.println("Timestamp: " + message.getJMSTimestamp() + "\tJMSDestination: " + message.getJMSDestination() + "\tReplyTo: " + message.getJMSReplyTo());
            if (message instanceof TextMessage)
                System.out.println("Data: " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());

            System.out.println("\n");

            if (counter >= 5) break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("stopping the topic");
    topicConnection.stop();
}
```

Attempting to make this cast gives me this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jms.client.WLSessionImpl cannot be cast to oracle.jms.AQjmsSession
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast it to that type because the client that your application is using isn't from the provider you think it is.  According to the exception the TopicSession is of a type provided by the WebLogic JMS client so that cast is doomed to failure.  You should look at your JNDI configuration and see if it is configured the way you seem to think it is configured.

Your JNDI Properties is telling the code where to create the ConnectionFactory from and that is getting you WebLogic client bits, you seem to want Oracle AQ bits so the ConnectionFactory that's looked up in the JNDI step needs to be an Oracle one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Java and I'd like to clarify exactly what you mean in your answer. Does this mean I need to review my import statements or classpath additions? My potentially relevant imports are as follows: 
`import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import oracle.jms.TopicBrowser;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import oracle.jms.AQjmsSession;`

Comment: It may or may not also be worth noting that whether or not I give what I believe to be a valid consumer name (using a clientID) in the createBrowser call, I get the same casting issue.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you import into you Java code, the TopicSession is an instance of a WebLogic TopicSession and you are trying to cast to an Oracle AQ TopicSession instance which will never...ever..ever work.  You need to change your JNDI Properties file to create a ConnectionFactory from Oracle AQ

Comment: Here is how I'm setting my inital context: `private InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException
    {
        System.out.println("Opening connection to " + SERVER);
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, SERVER);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, WLUSER);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, WLPASSWORD);
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }`

Comment: Where `public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";`. I've tried setting this to `JNDI_FACTORY="oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory";` but I get the following error: `javax.naming.NamingException: The configuration of the AQjmsInitialContext is not complete. The configuration must contain datasource or (db_url,java.naming.security.principal,java.naming.security.credentials) or both`

Comment: Seems like you need to learn how to configure OracleAQ which out of scope for this question.

Comment: So I've been mulling over your responses and I'm still a bit confused. Is the cast from TopicSession to AQjmsSession not the same cast that is being made in the official documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28420/jm_pblsh.htm#CHDEAAJI)?

Comment: Since you don't seem to know about casting from one concrete object type to another completely different concrete type I'm not really sure how to help you.